# Maximum uninterrupted value in binary tree in N jumps

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, theory

I have binary tree with nodes values.I have to get maximum way value(sum of the N connected nodes) in N jumps starting from the first node.Way must be uninterrupted, with free return to parent node.

My current algorithm:

1. For each last available node(that has 0 child's or 0 jumps).
2. Write into array current value and amount of available jumps.
3. Return to parent node, copy both arrays(if has 2 child's) or 1 array
       (1 child).
4. Repeat 1-3 until root node.
5. Based on array in root node,that store all available values, find
       maximum value.

Main questions:

1. Any better algorithm?
2. Any optimization for this algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum value?

Comment: maximum value of uninterrupted way with size of N.

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"? Also, is this question similar to this, https://projecteuler.net/problem=67 ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן "jump"- moving from parent node to children node.That's close example , but i also have free return to parent node .

Comment: What do you mean by "free return to parent node" or "uninterrupted"? It might help if you draw a picture to explain. Also draw a picture to show how your problem is different than Euler 67.

Comment: @גלעדברקן free return mean that i don't have to spend jump(which are limited to N) to return from child node to parent node.Uninterrupted means that it must be a way\path that connects N nodes(starting from root).Here's picture:http://imgur.com/01hvIPp for 2 jumps.Green is my task , red is Euler 67.

Comment: Oh, how do you know if you have "free return" from a specific node? Is it free return from all nodes, some specific nodes, only first child node from root, what?

Comment: @גלעדברקן from any child node to corresponding parent node.

Comment: Lol, I think you can better clarify all the rules... another question - so would jumping from lowest node back to root be "free"? free + free + free + free == free, no?

Comment: Yup , it will be free if that node is used.

Comment: @גלעדברקן And don't forget that road must start (or contain) from the root node.

Comment: (If it is not too much trouble, please add completed example answer with picture, correct answer calculation and explanation of correct answer calculation to the question post. I still don't understand the question...)

Comment: @גלעדברקן http://imgur.com/0bWRKrQ 10 nodes and 4 jumps. 1)Just a maximum path from root node , no free return used. 2)Used free return to return from 6 to 5 and get value of 7 (or return from 9 to 7 and then return to 5 and get value of 6 node) 3)Red is wrong because it has no connection to root node(1), but return used correctly.Green is okay bcs it has connection to root and has maximum value.

Comment: Ah, so each node can only get one free return to it? Like in your example 3) after you go down to 9 and then back to 7 and then down to 8 - now you are not allowed to go back to 7?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Nope , you can return to 7 as much as you want and then, for example, go to 5.I think i got what you didn't understood.You can visit ALL nodes(no restriction) , but final path must contain N nodes(because we have N jumps).Those nodes must be connected(path) and contain root node.Each connection require 1 jump, but if you connected child and parent node you can return from child node to parent (which are part of the path) for no cost and then connect parent node with second child(using 1 jump).

Comment: I see that example 3) in red has 5 "down jumps" but examples 1) and 2) have 4 down jumps. Is example 3) in red incorrect because it's using more than 4 down jumps and N=4? Also, I don't understand why you wrote, "no root connection" at example 3).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Path must contain root node("1" node).That's why red path in 3 is incorrect (it connects 5,6,7,8,9 nodes , no connection with root node).And if connect  red path with root that's gonna be 5 jumps(we have 4).So correct solve is green(that connect 1,5,7,8,9)